# Communication between node js and python - Send Complex data

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, node.js

Hello fellow programmers,

I am working on a Node.js project and I am trying to include some python (There is good reason why I have to include python). I don't know much about python and even less about how to use it with Node.js. Right now, I am trying to do send an **object containing multiple arrays of objects** to my python script and received back a blob (my python script creates files). I am wondering if someone has some experience can tell me what approach I should take. How can I send this and be able to translate it to something that python can use.

I am currently using PythonShell but I don't know if there is **better library for sending a complex**.

Here is what my array looks like:

```
   var object= 
   {
       component: 
       [
          {
            x: 20,
            y: 43,
            hidden: false,
            data: 
            [
               {
                 'key' : 'Subject2', 
                 'value' :
                 [
                     {
                      'name' : 'C001', 
                      'age' : 41
                     },
                     {
                      'name' : 'C002', 
                      'age' : 37
                     }
                ]
              }

      ],
      fields:
      [
      ...
      ]

 }
```

*Note: The sending back a blob is not really important. I can manage without it.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: So your back-end is written in two different languages? How do you manage that? Are two servers running? If that's the case, they can call each other and pass data this way.

Comment: The back-end is Node js but I am using a python script to generate files and send it back to the user. So it's on one server

Comment: What you call `array` is an object. That's a little bit confusing. You say you use `python-shell` to spawn and communicate with a Python process. So set the communication type to JSON and look at the Python examples how the Python end of the communication has to look like. What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far, parsed my array into a giant string and send it! I am going to look out how to set the communication type to JSON thx. And also sorry It si true, I will edit it (because I removed some content)